# (python) Does app.cget() not work with customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, customtkinter

I've tried to get the text from a button in customtkinter.

It works in normal tkinter with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(text="hello")
button.pack()

button_text = button.cget("text")
print(button_text)
```

But when applying the same idea to customtkinter it shows me this error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"

My code is:

```
from customtkinter import *

root = CTk()

button = CTkButton(text="hello")
button.pack()

button_text = button.cget("text")
print(button_text)
```

Comment: `.cget()` can only retrieve actual Tkinter attributes, and a CTKButton isn't actually a Button - it's something like a Frame containing a Canvas containing a drawing of a button.  In this case, I believe you can use `button.text` to retrieve or set the CTKButton's text - but I have no idea how you're supposed to know which technique to use in any given situation.

Comment: This makes sense now. `button.text` works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update customtkinter to the latest version. The `.cget` method was implemented after version 5.

```py
from customtkinter import *

root = CTk()

button = CTkButton(root, text="hello")
button.pack()

button_text = button.cget("text")
print(button_text)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, there was a bunch of binds missing in CustomTkinter 4. There seemed to be a push to get these rectified with v5.